# How to write my own operation over observable to map everything to a constant?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, rx-java, reactive-programming

I wrote my custom observable, which emits `LatLng` objects when user moves Google Map delibrately. Also I have

```
BehaviorSubject<Boolean> locationTracking = BehaviorSubject.create(false);
```

which I think will be property, indicating, whether map follows the user ("tracks location") or not.

The behaviour should be that once user touches the map, tracking should turn off. And user will be required to turn it on explicitly if he wish.

So I wrote

```
    // once map touched, this means turn off location tracking
    cameraMove(googleMap)
        .map(new Func1<LatLng, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(LatLng latLng) {
                return false;
            }
        }).subscribe(locationTracking);
```

here I made mapping from any location, emitted by map, to false value. The syntax appear is rather long, lambda syntax is prohibited by compatibility settings.

So, am I able to create my own operation, something like `mapAnyToFalse` and write

```
    // once map touched, this means turn off location tracking
    cameraMove(googleMap)
        .mapAnyToFalse()
        .subscribe(locationTracking);
```

It should be a member of `Observable`, which I can't touch. Are there any other means or ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no you cannot create such operator.

The closest syntax you can achieve would look like:

```
cameraMove(googleMap)
    .map( anyToFalse() )
    .subscribe(locationTracking);
```

If elsewhere in your code you would have a method:

```
public Func1<Object, Boolean> anyToFalse() {
    return new Func1<Object, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(LatLng latLng) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

(This method can be static and then statically imported)

Comment: You could also create a class which implements `Func1<Object, Boolean>`